# Allow Japanese Characters to Bypass C#s HtmlEncode method

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, unicode, character-encoding

I need to scrub data for malicious content in a form (whose website is UTF-8 encoded) so I'm doing the following:

`myTextBox.Value = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);` where `value` is the data to be placed in the TextBox.

This does correctly scrub malicious data such as Javascript calls, but also turns Japanese characters into their UTF-8 equivalents, such as `&#24859;`

Is there a way to skip those characters from being encoded, like some sort of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML character reference character sequence `&#24859;` (i.e. the eight single bytes `&`, `#`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `5`, `9`, `;` in their traditional ASCII values) representing a Unicode code point is not the same as a UTF-8 byte-sequence representing the UTF-8 encoding of that same code point (i.e. the 4 hex bytes 0xF0 0xA4 0xA1 0x99).

http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/

Which one is happening?

This simple console app shows that regular Unicode code points (assuming they do not represent an HTML-escape-needing thing like <) do not get translated:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lp = 0;
            string[] Inputs = {"\U00024859", "<tag>\U00024859<\\tag>"};
            foreach (var Test in Inputs)
            {
                string HTML = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Test);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(HTML != Test ? "String {0} Changed" : "String {0} Unchanged", lp));
                lp++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem is that the text is already converted to a character reference sequence, and HTML-Encode is assuming that you want to see the & characters.  Just like in my second example, where < gets converted to `&lt;`

Comment: HTML character reference character sequence (the first one)

Comment: @acconrad So your data is already partially encoded.  You need to decode the partially encoded data and encode the entire thing - not an easy thing.

Comment: So I'm essentially double-encoding this?

Comment: @acconrad Yes, essentially, it's as if someone typed `&#24859;` into your form, and you want it to re-appear that way and not be converted into something else.  The main problem is you are trying to avoid injection.  Because you are saying "I'm not going to let the browser interpret these codes, so I'm escaping them to be presented literally.", the browser then is not being allowed to interpret the character sequence.  Hopefully, someone with more experience dealing with this problem can chime in...

Comment: @acconrad HTMLDecode("&#24859;") seems to work (giving a unicode code point, which is not then changed by HTMLEncode) - but of course, what if HTMLEncode(HtmlDecode(malicious)) == malicious...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not an issue for you anymore, but I just had the same problem and found a solution I thought I should share with you.

The HttpUtility class has a method called HtmlAttributeEncode which will only encode quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx